# Möbius map from circles to lines

Tags: geometry

I want to find a Möbius transformation that takes the two circles $C(i,3), C(-i,1)$ to the parallel lines $Re(z)=0, Re(z)=1$. I know that they intersect at -2i, which means I have to map $2i \mapsto \infty$. I'm not sure how to ensure that both get mapped to the appropriate line. I've tried using 2 other points on each circle to define a map, but it's never worked out quite right.

In situation like this, are there any canonical choices of points to consider other than the obvious, like intersections and such?

Also, if I want to show that any four concyclic points can be mapped to $\pm 1, \pm k, k \in (0,1)$, does it just come down to comparing the cross ratios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the two circles. Here is a plan: just send the point $-2i$ to $\infty$ somehow. For instance, by $z \to 1/(z+2i)$. Then look at what happens to the circles. They will map to two parallel lines, but probably not the lines that you want. But this is not a problem: you can simply add a second transformation that will map the two lines that you have to the two lines that you want.

As for the second question, it probably does. Have you tried it?

**UPDATE:** Here is a more detailed answer to the second question. We have four distinct concyclic points and we need to prove that there is a Möbius transform that sends them to $\pm1,\,\pm k$ where $k \in (0,\,1)$. Here is a rough sketch of a proof.

Step 1. The points are concyclic, so there is a Möbius transformation that maps them all onto the real axis. So we can assume from the start that our 4 points are all on the real axis.

Step 2. We have 4 points $z_1,\,z_2,\,z_3,\,z_4$ on the real axis. Prove that there exists such a $k\in (0,1)$ that two cross-ratios are equal:
$$
    (z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)=(k,-k;1,-1).
$$
Technical detail: you might need to relabel points $z_i$ in a different order to do this.

Step 3. Now you can use the fact that Möbius transformations can be [specified by three points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Specifying_a_transformation_by_three_points). So there is a Möbius transformation $\omega$ such that $\omega(z_1)=k,\,\omega(z_2)=-k$ and $\omega(z_3)=1$. And you can prove that $\omega(z_4)$ will be automatically equal to $-1$ using the fact that $(z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)=(k,-k;1,-1)$. This is it.

Comment: I tried the second question using the cross ratio, but it doesn't tell me much, just that the ratio is real (which we already knew).

I'm thinking now that I want to prove there is a line that that the four points are symmetric in pairs with respect to. Then if I map that line to the imaginary axis, I'll get symmetric points $\pm a, \pm b$ which I can scale down as appropriate.

Comment: In general, such a line does not exist. If it existed then the 4 points would be vertices of a right trapezoid, which is not guaranteed. In this case it's probably easier to go with a more general approach and use the fact that Mobius trnasformations can be specified by three points. I've updated my answer with a brief explanation of the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Dan Shved's answer: I think you should choose the radius of the inversion circle around $-2i$ in such a way that the two lines end up having the desired distance between them. After that a rotation and translation will move them where you want.

[If after the inversion the lines have the wrong distance between them, I don't see how a rotation and/or translation can then map the lines where you want them.]

Comment: Rotations and translations may be not enough, but we also have homotheties. Although applying a homothety after an inversion is almost the same as choosing an appropriate radius of the inversion circle in advance.

Comment: That's what I did. Before, I tried mapping the imaginary axis to the real axis and $-2 \mapsto \infty$, since this would be the desired configuration, by $4i \mapsto 1, 0 \mapsto 0$. This didn't work, though. Turns out I had to do $4i \mapsto 0, 0 \mapsto 1$, which, I guess, had the same orientation as the original circles.